# Ionic 4 Loader is getting dismissed but data is not shown

Tags: ionic4

I want to show the loading controller until data is fetched from the server. But the loader is getting dismissed but data is not shown on the page.
I have posted two images. The first image shows data is not displayed on the page and the second image shows console.log values. I am getting proper values on console.log but not getting displayed.
If I refresh the page again it is working fine.
Whats gone wrong? Please help
[image]
[image]

.ts

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
constructor(public loadingController : LoadingController ) { }

async ngOnInit() {

     await this.presentLoading()

    this.razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key : 'XXXXXX',
      key_secret: 'XXXXXXX'
    })

    this.razorpay.once('ready', async (response) => {

      this.banks = response.methods.netbanking
      console.log(this.banks)

      this.display = true
      await this.dismiss()
    })

  }

  async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Hellooo',
    });
    await loading.present();
  }

  async dismiss() {

     await this.loading.dismiss();
    console.log('Loading dismissed!');
  }
}
```

.html

```
 <ion-list *ngIf="display">
   <ion-item  *ngFor="let bank of banks | keyvalue " (click)="selected_bank()">
    <ion-label>
      {{bank.value }}
    </ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright" slot="end"></ion-icon>

   </ion-item>

 </ion-list>
```

Comment: in your case look like your dismiss method call first after that create call.
this can happen because of cache. so you can  use timeout method in dismiss then check once that can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have just updated the question. Now I am able to dismiss the loader but can't display data. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try binding loading to class level property (loading) then call dismiss on it. Your current code seems like is calling dismiss on undefined var

```
export class HomePage {

  loading; // make a var at your class level here

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.presentLoading()

    this.razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key: 'XXXXXX',
      key_secret: 'XXXXXXX'
    })

    this.razorpay.once('ready', (response) => {

      this.banks = response.methods.netbanking
      console.log(this.banks)

      this.display = true

      this.dismissLoading()
    })

  }

  async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Hellooo',
    });
    await loading.present();
  }

  async dismissLoading() {
    if (this.loading) { // if the var contains the loader you can dismiss it
      await this.loading.dismiss();
      console.log('Loading dismissed!');
    }
  }

}
```

Please note in case Razorpay will respond with an error you might have indefinite loader problem. Ideally you should call dismiss on both success response and error response somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But now I am facing a strange problem. The loader is getting dismissed but data is not shown. If I again refresh page it is working fine. Thank you in advance